# Formatting a string in Unix

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed

```
$ landscape=aws,azure
$ echo $landscape
```

expected o/p:

```
aws-landscape,azure-landscape
```

How I am doing it now..!?

```
$ landscape=aws,azure
$ GITLANDSCAPE=$(echo $Landscapes | sed 's/,/-landscape,/g' | sed 's/$/-landscape/g')
$ echo $GITLANDSCAPE
```

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Please do add what is your GOAL here? What should be expected output. Please post all details in your post and let us know then.

Comment: What's your actual question? Is your code not working?

Comment: Could you give us your input and corresponding expected output please?

Comment: I am getting the desired o/p..!  i was just curious about the best way of doing it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replacing the comma is not a particularly good style.

You can do it like this:

```
landscape=aws,azure
echo $landscape | awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";OFS=",";suffix="-landscape"}{print $1suffix,$2suffix}'
```

Output:

```
aws-landscape,azure-landscape
```

In the `BEGIN` block you set the following variables:

- FS: field separator
- OFS: output field separator
- suffix: you can use a variable here, in case you want to change the text later and don't want to change the text on several places in the code

Comment: Really a nice one..!
Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

with sed, you can do as this:

```
echo $landscape | sed -E 's/,|$/-landscape&/g'
aws-landscape,azure-landscape
```

or, you can do with awk:

```
echo $landscape | awk -F, '{print $1"-landscape,"$2"-landscape"}'
aws-landscape,azure-landscape
```

Comment: @Guy, \0 means a fully match string.

Comment: I tried it out and found that, yes. It’s quite hard to search for more info tho! So unlike & which is just for specifically captured groups.. cheers.

Comment: I don't think that's portable to `sed` across the board, though. Is this a GNU  `sed` extension?

Comment: @tripleee, do you mean the option -E?

Comment: No, I mean the `\0`sequence, though it's probably a feature of the also nonstandard `-E` extension on whichever version of `sed` this is.

Comment: I would guess POSIX portable would be `s/,\|$/-landscape&/g` but the `\|` probably isn't fully portable back to pre-POSIX `sed`.

Answer (score 2):

Using a comma to delimit your strings is probably the main pain point here. The shell naturally supports space-separated tokens.

```
printf '%s-landscape\n' aws azure
```

If you want to do something a bit more complex, maybe a loop.

```
sep=''
for token in aws azure; do
    printf '%s%s-landscape' "$sep" "$token"
    sep=','
done
```

If you want to do something even more complex, perhaps put them in an array. (This is not Bourne/POSIX `sh` compatible, but a common extension in Ksh, Bash, etc.)

```
a=(aws azure)
for token in "${a[@]}"; do ...
```

As an aside, in Bash, there is also brace expansion:

```
printf '%s\n' {aws,azure}-landscape
```

This is tortured, but produces what you are asking:

```
printf '%s' {aws,\,azure}-landscape
```

The first comma separates the phrases between the braces. To include a literal comma in one of the phrases, we backslash it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you have a variable holding a comma-separated list of words. You want to add a fixed string, `-landscape`, to each of these words, keeping the comma as separator.

This is one way to do it, provided that none of the words contains white space:

```
words1=ab,cd,ef,gh
words2=$(printf %s $words1 | xargs --delimiter , -L 1 printf "%s-landscape " | fmt -1 | paste -d, -s)
echo $words2
```

This would print

```
ab-landscape,cd-landscape,ef-landscape,gh-landscape
```

How it works: The *xargs* tears apart the *words1* string into individual words and invokes *printf* to add *-landscape* to each. The resulting output is still separated by spaces, not by comma. With *fmt*, these words are put in separate lines, one line for each word. The final *paste* joins these lines with a comma.